# Custom UITableViewCell populated with timer?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having a problem with displaying time on `UITableViewCell`

```
unsigned long long seconds = milliseconds/1000;
unsigned long long minutes = seconds/60;
unsigned long long hours = minutes/60;

seconds -= minutes * 60;
minutes -= hours * 60;

NSString * result1 = [NSString `enter code here`stringWithFormat:@"%02lluH:%02lluM:%02lluS",hours,minutes,seconds];

self.menushowTime.text = result1;//populate cell label with time
```

Whenever I am reloading the table view my timer is running with 2x speed, I mean very fast. How can I prevent this from happening.

Comment: how are u calculating milliSeconds?

Comment: hm = components.hour * 3600000;
    NSUInteger mm = components.minute * 60000;
    NSUInteger sm = components.second * 1000;
    
    currentTime = hm + mm + sm;
    
    NSLog(@"show current time %lld ",currentTime);
    This is how i am calulating

Comment: and everything working fine,facing problem when i start scrolling tableview or reloading the tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
facing problem when i start scrolling tableview or reloading the tableview.?
```

Yes it happens, because timer is attached to `NSRunLoop`, so when the `UI thread` is busy doing animations , `NSRunLoop` has to halt. It finishes animations and later increments your timer. so the timer wont increase perfectly during this time.

use below one,

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: I am completely not getting how to fire my timer as m a newbie,could u please provide some good example for how to display time in uitableviewcell

Comment: you created a timer instance right, now add it to runLoop as shown

Comment: does the problem still persist?

Comment: no ,i solved that by firing my timer every second.Initially i was firing my timer every millisecond.Thanks a lot .and i also included commonmode and runloop with timer.

Answer (score 0):

**first calculate minutes, later seconds**.
Change your code to below.

```
minutes -= hours * 60;
seconds -= minutes * 60;
```